# align subfigures vertically in memoir

Tags: memoir, subfloats

I'd like to have the **two subfigures per caption** above each other. In the following MWE, they are horizontally aligned. Is there a way to force them to be vertically aligned?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}

 \begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \subbottom[$asd$]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \subbottom[$asd$]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \subbottom[$asd$]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: they are positioned like letters so currently you have a word-space between each, if you put a blank line before each `\subbottom` they are in separate paragraphs so come one under the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `tabular`, locally setting `\arraystretch` to 0 if you don't want space between the two images.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\subbottom[$asd$]{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{tabular}%
}
\subbottom[$asd$]{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{tabular}%
}
\subbottom[$asd$]{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{tabular}%
}
\end{figure}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}

 \begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \subbottom[$asd$]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

  \subbottom[$asd$]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

  \subbottom[$asd$]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}   

\end{document}
```

there is no special positioning code here you see the same if you compare

```
a
b
c
d
```

with

```
a

b

c

d
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was referring to the two images per caption. They are horizontally aligned now, I'd like for them to be vertically aligned

Comment: I tried using  \\ but that gives me an error